# how to increase precision as well as recall in svm for highly imbalanced data set

Tags: python-3.x, machine-learning, svm

I have loan data set with shape which is highly imbalanced:
(116058, 29)

how to improve precision and recall scores
target column m13
Counter({1: 636, 0: 115422})

I have used to split data in train and test set:

```
X_train,X_test,y_train,y_test = train_test_split(X,y,train_size = 0.8,random_state = 100,stratify = y)
```

and then used svm for classification:

```
svc = SVC(class_weight = {1:0.95,0:0.05},kernel='rbf')
svc.fit(X_train,y_train)
y_pred = svc.predict(X_test)
```

I got precision as .54 and recall as .55

I tried grid search as well with different value of C and gamma, the above code gave the best result

```
svc = SVC(class_weight = {1:0.95,0:0.05},kernel='rbf')
svc.fit(X_train,y_train)
y_pred = svc.predict(X_test)
```

is there any way to improve the precision as well as recall score?

Answer (score 0):

first of all let me comment the baseline of your prediction, If i understand you correct, you have 636 of class 1, and 115422 of class 0.

Imagen you would built a prediction model that always predicts class 0, your precision would be (if class 0 is your true class):

```
115422/(115422+636)=0,9945
```

and your recall (if class 0 is your true class):
1
If class 1 is your true class, precision would be: 0

As you can see it is quite a task to tune it. In general there are books about this topic, it will be super hard to tune it. But your target should be to predict the class 1 correctly! The goal should be to identify every class 1 in your algorithm. For example you could try to target your sensivity, here are some goals to target: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Precision_and_recall

What you defetnly should do, make sure that your train and test sets have target ofs class 1.